# Does compiler optimize this part of code (const getter)?

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-construction

I have the following class definition:

```
class foo {
  private:
    bool m_active;

  public:
    const bool isActive() const // (btw do I need return type `const bool&` here?)
    {
       return m_active;
    }  
};
```

1. Does a class with a `const` getter (`foo->isActive()`) work faster then `foo->m_active` (if it would be public)? I tried to look at disassembled code, but didn't find anything interesting.
2. Where can I read about `const` getters and setters? I need a deep understanding as to where and why these methods are used.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Oh, and returning a reference to a bool will never be faster than just returning the bool by value. It's a tiny type.

Comment: To your second question: How would `const` setters make sense? A setter should afterall change the value of a member variable, making it inherently non const. And what kind of deep understanding do you need?

Answer (score 8):

By default, all member functions are considered for function inlining. This means that the compiler will optimize out the entire function call and replace it with a direct access to the member.

So the answer is yes. The compiler will optimize it.

Comment: Assuming the relevant optimisation is enabled... compilers often default to no optimisation, but I don't know about IDEs.

Comment: @MarkB: Any modern compiler supports whole-program optimization.

Comment: True, hence why I added "considered" since there's a whole list of reasons that could prevent the function from being inlined. (recursion, large body, polymorphic, etc...) But in the context of simple getters and setters, they are almost always inlined with the relevant optimizations.

Comment: I find it *interesting* that you state *all **member** functions are considered for function inlining*, either you mean *all functions are considered for inlining* (whole-program optimization as GMan states) or else there is something that is missing from the description in the line of *all members **defined** inside the class definition are implicitly inline*.

Comment: I can't remember exactly where I read it, *member functions* were referring to functions defined inside a class. On GCC and VC++, if you turn the optimization level to max `-O3`, `/Oy` everything (not just member functions) is considered for inlining - with or without the `inline` modifier.